# "I'll delete my mostly-correct answer, as I've spent too much time on it already"

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I have asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68354072/how-can-i-left-align-elements-together-in-the-center-of-my-page-when-they-arent#68354296) and received an answer that mostly solves it. After some back and forth, the author of this answer has informed me in a comment, that they spent too much time on it already, and as such they will delete it (??).

I am quite puzzled on several aspects of this situation. I do not understand why one would want to delete an answer because of the time spent improving it, but the particular logic doesn't seem to matter here. Judging by the reputation and badges of the answerer, I would've guessed that they are quite well-acquainted with the policies and mechanisms of SO. Is there a reason why no answer would be preferable to a mostly correct one? Is there an interaction of rules that creates a perverse incentive here?

FWIW, I believe that this answer would be a net-positive to Stack Overflow as a Q&A database.

Comment: It is quite irritating to spend time answering a question, and then end up in an unpaid consulting session you never intended to be a part of. Right or wrong, removing the answer removes the ability to continue it.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, removing the answer effectively ends the conversation.  I confess to having done this a couple of times, for the reasons Kevin B. has already stated.

Comment: Being the original OP of the answer in question I'll just say this. As someone who genuinely enjoys answering peoples questions on SO, and not just to point horde but to help people, there still has to be some pragmatism applied to how much time you invest per answer. It's nothing personal, but most of us also make a living doing this stuff. Your question could have easily led me down a dozen alternative methods and nothing personal, but I also value my free time and had clocked out for the day. In the end, it's up to the person volunteering their time to help as their choice. Cheers

Comment: @KevinB I completely understand wanting to end the conversation. However, stating "I spent too much time and won't be continuing the conversation" is just as effective, and not destructive. I don't think deleting the answer is a healthy solution, as it might be valuable anyway, either to the asker, or other potential answerers.

Comment: @ChrisW. It's quite understandable that you don't want to get into a protracted discussion about improving/editing the answer. However, if you feel that the answer you wrote addressed the question sufficiently, you don't *have* to get into a discussion about it. You could say that you'd rather not discuss it further, or simply stop engaging entirely. Deleting (what appears to be) a useful answer just because you don't want to engage with the OP, is not really necessary.

Comment: If the answer was so useful why didn't you accept it?

Comment: @ChrisW. I am not at all trying to imply that limiting the time you spend on any given question is bad, merely that the deletion seems counterproductive.

Comment: Well folks I'm of the opinion I'm caught in a catch 22 scenario here now. Had I continued to go down the road of back-and-forth which I'm commonly willing to accommodate whose to say how much more free time would have been volunteered. Now by bowing out of the question I've become a subject of criticism as well. Personally, wasn't expecting it to become a thing, I'll swing back to it later if it nukes the additional overhead being created here :D PS - I got down-voted between iterations as it was, can't please everyone lol.

Comment: Deleting the answer and bowing out of a chameleon question are not mutually exclusive. All you have to do to stop participating in an unpaid consulting session is to *stop participating*. If necessary, flag comments with a custom flag to request that they be deleted by a moderator. There's no point in leaving the comments there if you aren't going to answer them.

Comment: @RobertLongson Accepting an answer implies the problem is solved. In this case, I wasn't yet sure whether the road outlined ends in the state I want to achieve, as in my experience of CSS, small visual details can require an entirely different approach. Had Chris not deleted the answer, I probably would've accepted it by now (and edited in my changes), having wrestled with the beast of CSS some more and achieved my goal.

Comment: Your problem couldn't be solved, because you moved the goal post to keep this tutoring session going.

Comment: @ChrisW. When you feel continually pressed for further assistance, there's a big difference between "not assisting any further" and "removing all previous assistance". The first is perfectly reasonable, while the second is purely spiteful. By the way, it is "hoard", not "horde".

Comment: @ChrisW. Also, "*I got downvoted between iterations as it was*" - I don't see a downvote on the answer currently. It looks like whoever downvoted you did so because your solution didn't address OP's need, and after further changes, the alleged downvote was removed. This is exactly how SO *should* work.

Comment: @TylerH I think calling my action of bowing out "spiteful" is a bit dramatic, but when it comes down to it the capacity of which someone chooses to volunteer (especially when they genuinely are just trying to help and 99.9% of the rest of the time go out of their way to do so) is solely up to them, period. However thanks for the grammar catch, was a long day. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That answerer doesn't owe anybody here anything. If they felt that the best way to extricate themselves from that situation was to delete the answer, then more power to them. The fact that SO has an irrevocable right to the information they've already posted is shouted here so often. If the issue really is that we're losing valuable info by having it deleted on Chris's account, then have someone who can see it copy it to a new answer, with appropriate attribution. Problem solved.

Comment: @ChrisW. Why else would you delete your *upvoted* answer, if not to spite the asker who kept asking clarification/and-then-what questions? If OP has concerns about potential shortcomings of your answer, that's fine; not every ask is going to have a 100% satisfactory answer with all edge cases addressed (in fact most probably won't). If your answer was unhelpful, it's one thing, but someone clearly thought it *was* helpful since they upvoted it... and you still decided to remove that content, purely because OP was curious about aspects of it? Come on, that doesn't pass the smell test.

Comment: @ChrisW. If you want to start charging money for your time and effort, fine, ask the user to join you for a session on CodeMentor or somewhere. But please leave aside the gross "most of us do this for a living" talk; you knew perfectly well *before* answering that you were providing that answer 100% for free. There is never an expectation on either party in a Q&A that someone should be willing to pay to get your help on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @ChrisW. - You deleted your answer, because you didn't want to participate, in the endless cycle of questions.  You could have simply just flagged those comments.  I face that situation often, I just tell the individual, that my answer addresses the question as it was written.  Now if the question is not clear enough, and should be improved, it should be downvoted and closed. While I agree the situation you were in was tough, I can't agree with just removing the answer, without the question being at least closed for not being clear.

Comment: @MikeM. I would consider the ideal situation to be addressing the issue and having the deleter undelete the post themselves, rather than encourage another somewhat-spiteful action of end-running around what little agency the deleter still has. But it *did* occur to me.

Comment: @TylerH With all due respect, it's an easy task to criticize after the fact. However in the moment I was juggling multiple other things and simply made a choice to which you're apparently very opinionated about the outcome of. You're entitled to your criticisms and if it makes you feel better after my meetings I'll go un-delete and answer the question in full to whatever capacity if it puts a stop to this ridiculous distraction. However, let me reiterate. The capacity to which an individual chooses to volunteer their time is entirely up to their discretion regardless of feelings about it sir.

Comment: @TylerH There is no "issue" here. The only thing that this boils down to is that Chris didn't freely volunteer their time and expertise exactly as some would like, and indeed expect. I doubt that any of those presumptuous people are Chris's parent, spouse, or employer, though, so I'm not sure how they think they have the right to do that. There is a sickeningly increasing attitude that the people actually providing the answers here need to behave like employees and just stay in line, with all of the associated grief and blowback, but none of the benefits.

Comment: @MikeM.  What this gentleman says, bravo. Let's be honest here folks. We come here most often on the side of answering questions because we enjoy helping fellow nerds out, and often learning something in the process also. Personally, I care much more about knowing I helped someone than about the points and if I did I'd easily have a significantly higher score. However this sort of interaction feels draconian for something we lend our time to for free and not even get a free t-shirt or something. All this form of public guilt display does is make me want to take a break from it which is sad.

Comment: @ChrisW. I understand 'heat of the moment' situations... but the answer is still deleted 16 hours after you first saw this concern raised on Meta and responded. So it seems this wasn't just a 'heat of the moment' situation. Anyway, I don't see anyone criticizing the decision not to continue contributing to that Q&A; what is being criticized is the "takeback" behavior; giving a gift to the asker and the community by contributing an answer, and then saying "sike! I'm taking this one back".

Comment: @TylerH I can't tell any longer if you mean to be an antagonist here or what exactly is the purpose of your over-bearing posture. I'm currently multi tasking responses here on a side screen while sitting in meetings, I will circle back to the original question soon when I can give it some genuine focus.....now if that displeases you, I don't know what to do for you amigo but your tone is exceedingly unnecessary. Signing off, will deal with the OP when I choose that I can............................

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm simply addressing the issues I see in your responses/argument for why you took the action you did. Also, there's no expectation that you sit here and wait for responses to come in. You *can*, of course, always go on with your personal life before commenting on Stack Overflow, just like you can stop responding to excessive requests for clarification under your answers from OP or others, in case that still needs reiterating.

Comment: @Tom I don't see when I moved the goalposts. Could you clarify?

Comment: jfc this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: I wouldn't want to leave a mostly-correct answer dangling if I had to abandon it for one reason or another. Correct or nothing.

Comment: Side note: This also is precisely why it's not worth commenting, most of the time, on why a question was closed or a post was downvoted. Just walk away. There's less avoidable drama.

Answer (score 23):

The incentive to delete it is that presumably it's not a complete and correct answer to the question. If it was you could have accepted it and that would have prevented its deletion.

Did you upvote the answer yourself? If not then you're really not telling us that the answer you received was better than no answer at all.

The answer was upvoted so the answerer has lost 10 rep by deleting it although since they have more than 20,000 rep already that's not really going to make a material difference. The system has therefore incentivised the retention of the answer in a minor way.

As to why, they seem to have deleted it because they realised that the question was not entirely clear. When they answered it you changed the question to emphasize some part of the answer that didn't meet your needs. The answerer then updated the answer again but when you indicated that that still wasn't sufficient they gave up. It seems they were worried that the question was starting to turn into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Next time try to make sure your question completely covers your requirements from the off rather than adding additional information in at a later date once you realise it's not quite an accurate and complete description of what you actually want.

Comment: The requirement was there from the start. I didn't add it in an edit, but merely clarified it and added italics, so that it is more compatible with skimming.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the opinion of the answerer according to your and their back and forth comments on the answer. If you argue in comments that the answer isn't right for you then one of two things are likely to happen a) the answerer might update the answer or b) they might delete it. In this case you actually got both, one after the other.

Comment: Once again Mr. Longson for the win. If some more free time I'll revisit but he's pretty much got the thought captured.

Comment: @NieDzejkob: While your question may have seemed perfectly clear to you from the beginning, you cannot make assumptions on how clear a question is to others, and your post-answer attempts to clarify it further can seem to a reasonable person as shifting requirements, something that can be very frustrating to deal with.